# Sequel Pro multiple update query with case and random variable

Tags: mysql, variables

Alright, so I have a table that has a count field that is between 0 and 100.  Up to six of these fields are tied to a single id.  I need to run an update that will decrease each of these rows by a different random number between 1 and 3.

I know I can get my random value with:

```
CAST(RAND() * 3 AS UNSIGNED)
```

And I know I can get my update to work with:

```
UPDATE Info SET Info.count = CASE WHEN Info.count < 2 THEN 0 ELSE Info.count - 2 END WHERE Info.id = $iid AND Info.type = 'Active';
```

(This just makes sure I will never dip below 0)

But I cannot combine them for the obvious reason that my random number will be different when evaluated then when it's set...

```
UPDATE Info SET Info.count = CASE WHEN Info.count < CAST(RAND() * 3 AS UNSIGNED) THEN 0 ELSE Info.count - CAST(RAND() * 3 AS UNSIGNED) END WHERE Info.id = $iid AND Info.type = 'Active';
```

Now I don't want to save just 1 variable, because I may need up to 6 different numbers...is there a way to do what I want to do in a single query?  I know how I can do it in multiple, but I really shouldn't be running up to 6 queries every time I need to update one of these blocks...

The table structure I'm working off of is:

```
CREATE TABLE `Info` (
  `id` int(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTOINC` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AUTOINC`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The AUTOINC field at the moment is just so I can easily verify what's going on during testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off writing a procedure to do this.  So you could write something to the extent of (pseudo code)

```
create procedure update() 
begin

     declare id, count, sub int;
     declare c cursor for select id, count floor(1+rand()*3) from info 
                           where type='Active';

     open c;
     loop
           fetch c into id, count, sub;
           update info set case count - sub < 0 then 0 else count - sub end 
            where id = id; 
     end loop;
     close c;

end
//
```

Or you can change the procedure to accept an ID like I had it before and simply use one select and one update statement.

Comment: "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

My test case I have setup at the moment has 3 Active, 1 Inactive -- so the subquery is returning 3 of them.

Comment: Also you forgot to name your derived table (Every derived table must have its own alias) but that was an easy fix.

Comment: If that's the case, how is it that your manual update works?  You would be setting all of the row counts to whatever last row the query finishes on.

Comment: Er, I'm not entirely sure how to answer your question.  But I know that if I set the manual counts to 90, 80, 70, 10 (last inactive) and run that query, my table reports 88, 78, 68, 10 (last skipped as should be).  I'll add the table structure to the original question perhaps that will help clarify.

Comment: The above is exactly the environment I'm working on, but it's a partial recreation of a live system that I simplified for myself so I could just address the problem at hand.  The extra data doesn't come into play.  There is no PK on the live table, but it could be created from the user_id and the state_id of the two different tables this one actually refers to.  As to your most recent question: id 1, AUTOINC 1, count 100 should get a different random number than id 1, AUTOINC 2, count 36.  I'm probably either going to just run multiple queries or use one random number, ugh.

Comment: I see.  I updated the answer a bit.  Hopefully I understood what you're saying and this could work.  Pretty sure each loop of the cursor should create a random number but if it doesn't, you can easily write a new select statement in the loop to get a new one each time.